# I write this program in cpp and when I print the variable `amount` I get some unusual value..why is it?

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>

int main(){
    int value = 0, amount, set = 0;
    std::cout << amount << std::endl;
}
```

on executing this file i get `650` as a result, why is it so??.

[this is the image of the code and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Cp7.png)

I was just trying to print a varibale in c++!!

Comment: Read about the concept of undefined behavior. Reading an uninitialized variable causes undefined behavior.

Comment: You initialized `value` and `set`, but not `amount`. What do you expect it to output when you don't initialize it? Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: What value did you expect it to print? If you expected `0`, then why are you initializing `value` and `set` to `0` explicitly?

Comment: Since `value` and `set` are unused, I don't see why they need to be in this program at all. Please increase the level of compiler warnings and/or pay attention to them. A compiler should warn when you attempt to read from an uninitialized variable.

Comment: You never set `amount` to any particular value, yet you have some unstated expectation of how it should print. When asking such questions you should at least say what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 6):

Your `amount` variable is *uninitialized*, as you are not assigned any value to it, so your code exhibits **undefined behavior**. The variable has whatever *random* value was previously stored in the memory block that it occupies.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, whenever you declare a variable that has not been explicitly assigned a value, it contains "garbage data".

When you declare a variable without initializing it, its value is undefined, and it can contain any arbitrary data left over from previous operations or the state of memory at the time of declaration. This data is often unpredictable and can lead to bugs and unexpected behavior in your program.

That is exactly what is happening with your `amount` variable.

Comment: Strictly speaking only the last paragraph of this answer is true. The rest is half truths. All C++ says is that using a uninitialised variable causes undefined behaviour.